# ng-model does not update after changing checked property

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have made simple checkbox list with elements such as:

```
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" />Aaaaa
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Also there is jquery script that highlights row when checkbox is checked and vice-versa it sets `.prop("checked")` when user clicks `<a>`(close to item's border). And problem is that I don't know why ng-model doesn't update model when clicking `<a>`

Here is sample. To reproduce problem click on text (this is ok), and click close to item's border.
http://plnkr.co/edit/sStCMaBaU1SsQ7hukfaZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-click directive to slove this problem.
I changed your Code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" ng-click="ChangeCheckBox">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value1" />Aaaaa
      </label>
    </a>
  </li>
```

and in your Controller:

```
$scope.ChangeCheckBox = function(){
 var t = $scope.value1;
 $scope.value1 = !t;
}
```